# Manually bootstrap angular app to create async app initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, bootstrapping

I am trying to manually bootstrap my angular app in order to load some data asynchronously that my app relies on.  See this [article](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data)

The problem is no matter what I try I cant get access to an instance of a factory using angular.injector.  See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yYSHJmWrFoQ3LZB2DN9T?p=preview)

The problem is anytime I run code like this:

```
var Injector = angular.injector(["MyAPP", "ng"]);
var initService = Injector.get("MyService");
```

I just get unknown provider errors.

Can someone  please help me make this plunker work, or point me to a better way to create an angular app initialization service. thanks,

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you posted, but there really isn't much there. Can you provide a plunkr that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the official documentation? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Comment: GPicazo, if you look at the plunker you will see that the app is not bootstrapping because initApp is throwing an error due to an unknown provider isssue.  the root of my question is how to get the injector service to acctually work and allow access to a factory instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**: Updated to reflect our discussion in the comments thread.

To setup the `initApp()` function to initialize, asynchronously using a Promise, any app level services required, including the factories (as defined in the original plunker) you can have it simply return a Promise that will resolve when the initial injections are complete; and once that is done, call your `bootstrapApplication()` method to bootstrap Angular on the page.

```
function initApp() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var Injector = angular.injector(["ng","plunker"]);
        Injector.invoke(['factoryTwo', function(factoryTwo) { 
          console.log(factoryTwo.test);
          resolve();
        }]);
  });
}


function bootstrapApplication() {
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ["plunker"]);
  });
}  

initApp().then(bootstrapApplication);
```

Here's a link to the forked plunker with the above code snippet working: http://plnkr.co/edit/764AqLZf6rQHwPZ1RAZc?p=preview

Comment: The whole point is to make initApp a promise and bootstrap the app after the promise is fuffiled. Also this does not make it work, if you look at the console the initApp function is throwing an error.

Comment: also the angular object and methods are available before bootstrapping

Comment: True, I hadn't had the console opened. Here's a fork of that plunker with the `initApp` working as  Promise and loading the Factory.  Needed to load `ng` via injector before `plunker` as well; but this works as you describe:

http://plnkr.co/edit/764AqLZf6rQHwPZ1RAZc?p=preview

Comment: Hey David awesome this works. Thanks!  Unfortunately it still is not working in my main app. I get --> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $location <- $urlRouter <- $state. I think this is because i need to inject something else besides just ng.  do you know what it is that i need to inject.

Comment: If you click that link in the console it should take you to an Angular error page that might give you more detail.  I don't know what else you're depending on.

Comment: @AlexHaines did you get more info from the error link?

Comment: Try injecting `'ui.router'`, which is what the error messages seems to be pointing to I believe.

Comment: Hey David thanks for all your work on this. I tried adding ui.router, i thought that was the issue as well. still no luck. I think i am just going to refactor to a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

you must bootstrap loaded ajax content before insert in page

You need to call `$compile` on the HTML string before inserting it into the DOM so that angular gets a chance to perform the binding.

In your fiddle, it would look something like this.

```
$("#dynamicContent").html(
  $compile(
    "<button ng-click='count = count + 1' ng-init='count=0'>Increment</button><span>count: {{count}} </span>"
  )(scope)
);
```

Obviously, `$compile` must be injected into your controller for this to work.

Read more in the [`$compile` documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile).